# Excel: How to trigger a macro when data is entered in the last row of a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I've been hunting across forums for an answer to this but no luck; hoping the good users at this forum will be able to help?

I need an Excel macro to be **triggered** when data is entered into the last row of a table. (The data range in question has been formatted as a table, and named Table 1)

This obviously means the trigger cell will move every time the table expands (when new data is entered).

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last row fairly elegantly as

```
INDEX(Table1,ROWS(Table1),)
```

I'd suggest making this a named range and then using that as your `Worksheet_SelectionChange` target for your macro. The named range can be accessed like this:

```
Workbooks("WorkbookName.xlsx").Names("RangeName")
```